# Autoclick an "a" link on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am having trouble attacking this problem and looking for a little insight.

So what I want is that when the page loads it calls the function called loadFromPdb() but the function is nested into another function which makes it tough.

The code

**Start of the demo.js file**

```
require(['pv'], function(PV) {

pv = PV;
var io = pv.io;
var structure;

$(document).foundation();
$('#load-from-pdb').click(loadFromPdb);

function loadFromPdb() {
 var pdbId = "1r6a";
 this.value = '';
 this.blur();

//Set up the URL
 var url = 'http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/' + pdbId + '.pdb';
   urlPdb = url;
   console.log(url);
    io.fetchPdb(url, function(s) {
        structure = s;
        cartoon();
        viewer.autoZoom();
 });
}
```

So in here I have a document foundation and when the id load from pdb is clicked it runs a request and grabs the pdb file from the database and then loads the structure of the protein on a canvas.

**The HTML5**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

<script src='js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/foundation-5.4.7.min.js"></script>
<script data-main='demo' src='js/require.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/foundation.css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/protein-style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "loading"></div>
<div id = "page">
<div id = "viewer-wrap">
    <div id="viewer">
        <canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>
        <nav id = "nav-bar" class = "top-bar" data-topbar role = "navigation">
            <section class = "top-bar-section">
                <div id="static-label">
                </div>
                <div class = "row-collapse"></div>
                <ul class = "right">
                    <li class="has-dropdown">
                        <a href="#">PDBs</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a id = sequence-pdb href="#">Sequence of Methyl Transferase</a> </li>
                            <li><a id = sequence-remove-pdb href="#">Remove Sequence</a> </li>
                            <li><a id = hoverOn href="#">Hover</a> </li>
                            <li><a id = hoverOff href="#">Hover Off</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class = "has-dropdown">
                        <a  href="#">Style</a>
                        <ul id = selectionGraphics class = "dropdown">
                            <li><a id = style-cartoon href ="#" >Cartoon</a></li>
                            <li><a id = style-lines href ="#" >Lines</a></li>
                            <li><a id = style-spheres href ="#" >Spheres</a></li>
                            <li><a id = style-balls-and-sticks href ="#" >Balls and Sticks</a></li>
                            <li><a id = style-points href ="#" >Points</a></li>
                            <li><a id = style-sline href = "#" >Smooth Line Trace</a></li>
                            <li><a id = style-trace href="#">Trace</a> </li>
                            <li><a id = style-tube href="#">Tube</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Color</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a id=color-uniform href="#">Uniform</a></li>
                            <li><a id=color-chain href="#">Chain</a></li>
                            <li><a id=color-element href="#">Element</a></li>
                            <li><a id=color-ss href="#">Secondary Structure</a></li>
                            <li><a id=color-ss-succ href="#">Secondary Structure Succession</a></li>
                            <li><a id=color-rainbow href="#">Rainbow</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Shading</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a id=phong href="#">Phong</a></li>
                            <li><a id=hemilight href="#">Hemilight</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>

        </nav>
        <div id = "sequence-label" class="scrollingDiv">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = 'picked-atom-name'>&nbsp;</div>
    <input type="image" src="photo-camera.png" id="snapshot" />
    <input type="image" src="download-button.png" id="download" />
</div>
```

**Things I have tried**

So what I did try is having a button and hiding it so that it autoclicks and then calls the load from pdb function like so

```
<button class ="md-trigger" id="load-from-pdb" data-modal= "modal">
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#load-from-pdb").trigger("click");
                });
            </script>
        </button>
```

which didn't seem to work. I have tried

```
 <body onload = "pv.loadFromPdb()">
```

but it has trouble finding the function and I also cannot figure out why because I strongly feel like that would make it easier. It just returns that the function is locked and I can't grab it or make it run.

I tried having a separate script with the same function in the HTML but that makes a mess of problems with calling other functions within that function.

So my question is how do I loadFromPdb() function in the HTML page when it loads?

Comment: The first idea should have worked, but you complicated it by putting the script inside the button.  Just add that script to the page as normal, rather than inside the button.  If that doesn't work then there's something stopping it, as `$('#load-from-pdb').trigger("click");` is correct.

Comment: I added the script to the end of the body tag but alas it still doesn't work when the page loads.

Comment: can you add [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) link

Comment: I shall attempt to

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fuueu3oq/ Trimmed it down a ton to see if it could work but yeah still nothing.

Comment: It may simply be that the button event handler hasn't been assigned at the time you try to trigger it. Try opening the console and pasting the trigger command in there, to check it works.

Comment: So I did try clicking the button after and it works fine. I guess it doesn't read the trigger event when it is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, far from it, but easy, fast and dirty: create a "clone" of your original function, now not nested, and then call it by your "body onload". Later you find a cleaner solution (please, do not downvote cause my answer is an answer as valid as any other - if it's ugly etc, then it's another case, but it's not wrong and works. Remember: "Perfect is the enemy of good". If you have better solution, please be positive: share it). Thank you.

Comment: I did attempt to clone my function inside of the demo.js but I guess the issue I am having is that when function calls it runs other things that are nested within the previous function and it just starts to make a mess of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem,

So in my Javascript file I wrote a "OnReady" function and from there it must of been messing with the scripts so in the end I just added the trigger event to the OnReady and it worked! Using the invisble button.

```
function onReady(callback) {
var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 1000);
function checkReady() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
        callback.call(this);
    }
}
}


function show(id, value) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
}


onReady(function() {
  show('page', true);
  show('loading', false);
  // Click the invisible button to simulate a loading of the PDB file
  $("#load-from-pdb").trigger("click");
});
```